# The buttons for my HTML, CSS, JS calculator is coming out in various sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

## Intro

Hello! I'm still very new to coding in general and using platforms like Stackoverflow, GitHub, etc so I apologize in advance if I have done something incorrectly within this post as well.

It is also my first post so please let me know of any corrections to make so I know how to make a more coherent posts in the future.

## Problem

I have followed a HTML, CSS, & JS calculator tutorial online and have done the same exact step, however, when I ran the code my buttons have came out in different sizes as shown in the image below:
[image of the buttons in different sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKIG.png)

This is a screenshot of the video's code:
[Calculator tutorial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiZxt.png)

I'm unsure of how to pinpoint my errors.

This is the code that I have up till the point where I encountered this error:

```js
function insert(num) {
  document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + num
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  font-size: 25;
  margin: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textview {
  width: 217;
  margin: 5;
  font-size: 25;
  padding: 5;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <form name="form">
      <input class="textview" name="textview">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value="C"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="<"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="/"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="x"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="button" type="button" value="7"></td>
          <td><input class="button" type="button" value="8"></td>
          <td><input class="button" type="button" value="9"></td>
          <td><input class="button" type="button" value="-"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="button" type="button" value="4"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="2"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="3"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is the issue possibly within the style element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found typo error in you input tag, just you have to write "class" where you have written "type", see below for better understanding.

```
<td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
<td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
<td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
```

Change to :

```
<td><input class="button" value="5"></td>
<td><input class="button" value="6"></td>
<td><input class="button" value="+"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        function insert(num){
            document.form.textview.value=document.form.textview.value+num
        }
```

```html
<style>
*{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.button{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px; 
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.textview{
    width: 217px; 
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px; 
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form name="form">
            <input class="textview" name="textview">
            <table>
               <tr>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="C"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="<"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="/"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="x"></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="9"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="-"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="6"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `<input>` elements do not have a `class="button"` as well as a `type="button"`.

You need *both* - the `type` attribute to set the input type to button (or it will be a text box), and the `class` attribute for the appropriate CSS styles.

The body should look like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form name="form">
            <input class="textview" name="textview">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="/"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="x"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="9"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="-"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="6"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```